# PostgreSQL array column in Oracle

Tags: arrays, oracle

In postgresql I can do following:

```
create table test(
    arrcolumn character varying(100)[]
)

insert into test(arrcolumn) values ('{bla,blubber}');
```

How can I create the same in oracle?

There is something called VARRAY but it seems not to work in sql tables only in PL/SQL procedures and functions?

Comment: More often than not, the use of arrays in Postgres is a bad decision to begin with. If you create a properly normalized data model (using a standard one-to-many relationship) then you can easily port this to other databases as well.

Answer (score 0):

> There is something called VARRAY but it seems not to work in sql tables only in PL/SQL procedures and functions?

That is incorrect; it does work in tables.

---

Define your data type:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_array AS VARRAY(100) OF VARCHAR2(50);
```

Then use it in the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  id        INT
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
            PRIMARY KEY,
  arrcolumn string_array
);
```

Then you can insert values:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (
  arrcolumn
) VALUES (
  string_array('bla', 'blubbler')
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=825ec31c13ff77731ee446f31038068c)*

---

> Do you know if this can also be unlimited?

Use a nested table:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_array AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50);

CREATE TABLE test (
  id        INT
            GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
            PRIMARY KEY,
  arrcolumn string_array
) NESTED TABLE arrcolumn STORE AS test__arrcolumn;
```

Or you can use two tables.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=974ea1baa9c709533ef4f4cceef1f295)*

Comment: the size of the array is set to 100. Do you know if this can also be unlimited?

Comment: @HasanTuncay Yes, use a nested table rather than a `VARRAY`.

Comment: Nested table is not equivalent to array: order of elements in an array has meaning, while nested tables are unordered (multi)sets. Oracle implements nested tables as arrays - and, idiotically, supports access by index - but it is not clear that order is preserved when nested tables are used in SQL. The documentation states explicitly that elements in a nested table are not ordered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array data type maintained by the system itself, instead of defining your own. Something like this. Notice the syntactical differences: in Oracle you must use the type name for constructor (you can't just give the values, they must be given in a constructor).

The maximum number of elements in a sys.odci*list array is **32767** - no doubt because Oracle, for whatever reason, uses signed 16-bit integers to index into an array. (I can understand 16-bit, for compatibility with oldest versions, but why ***signed***?)

```
create table t (arrcolumn sys.odcivarchar2list);
insert into t (arrcolumn) values (sys.odcivarchar2list('bla', 'blubber'));
select * from t;

ARRCOLUMN                             
--------------------------------------
ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('bla', 'blubber')
```

Then, if you need to access the elements in an array value (in the column), you can use the `table` operator, for example:

```
select column_value from t, table(arrcolumn);

COLUMN_VALUE
------------
bla
blubber
```